# redirect including input type value at submit form

Tags: html, forms, input

Any thoughts why this redirect doesn't work at form submit? It should redirect the user to the url specified in the js function, appending the value from the input form

```
 <form>
                            <div class="input-wrap">
                                <input type="text" id="myInputType" class="block"  />
                                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="block" onsubmit="redirect()" />
                            </div>
 </form>

`
<script type="text/javascript">
    function redirect() {
        window.location = 'http://somewhere.com?url=' + document.getElementByID('myInputType').value;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the `onsubmit=''` goes to a form tag like this `<form onsubmit="redirect();">` not on input

Answer (score 0):

You could receive the same result without using javascript.

You can use the method `GET` on your form and make the `action` the website you want to redirect to. Then all you have to do is add a `name` attribute to your input field and you got the same result.

Like so:

```html
<form method="GET" action="http://somewhere.com" >
    <div class="input-wrap">
       <input type="text" name="url" id="myInputType" class="block"  />
       <input type="submit" class="block" />
    </div>
 </form>
```

This will redirect to http://somewhere.com?url=yourinput

Answer (score 0):

The correct function name is `document.getElementById` not `document.getElementByID`

Answer (score 0):

1. Submit events fire on forms, not on buttons
2. `getElementById` has a **lower-case** `d`
3. Submitting a form is likely to override your attempt to assign a URL to a `location`
4. You've failed to encode the input value for URLs with `encodeURIComponent`.

There's no reason to use JavaScript for this. Just use a regular form submission.

```
 <!-- Set the action to the URL (without query string) you want to submit to. -->
 <form action="http://somewhere.com">
    <div class="input-wrap">
        <!-- Give the input the name of the field you want to send -->
        <input type="text" class="block"  name="url" >
        <!-- Don't give the submit button a name -->
        <input type="submit" class="block">
    </div>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few things need to be corrected.

1. use `document.getElementById` in place of `document.getElementByID`
2. `Onsubmit` is a form attribute not button so use `onClick`
3. if you want to use `onSubmit` then use it with form
4. Use `encodeURIComponent` function to avoid java-script errors.